# Not able to change TextFormField Border Width

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change width of the border of `TextFromField`, but it's not working.

Here is my code below.

```
TextFormField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white,width:2)),
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                labelText: 'Enter your username or email address'
                ),
),
```

Comment: I've tried your code and by changing the ```width``` property from 2 to 5 I saw the border get bigger, maybe it's because of the white color (so you can't see it properly) or perhaps it's a parent widget in which case you'd need to post a bit more code

Comment: no there is no problem with the border color, i already tried without color

Comment: After copy pasting your code I managed to successfully change the border width by just changing the 2 to a 5 so I'm not exactly sure what your problem is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the `enableBorder`. Try something like this

```
TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 10)),
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              labelText: 'Enter your username'),
        )
```

**Reference here:**

[InputDecorarion Class Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)

[BorderSide Class Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BorderSide-class.html)

Comment: This works for me thanks , from where i can get the more information about the above, is it written in flutter doc-> i searched but i didn't get this solution